# How to implement the fling for a custom view

Tags: android, onfling

I have a custom view which draw something accroding to a certain parameter(`center`).

Once the user move the view I will re-draw the view.(I make this by using the `GestureDetector` and override the `onScroll` method).

However now I want to implement the fling effect. I know I have to do something insid the `onFling` method.

But I do not know how to make it.

It seems that `OverScroller.fling` is what I want.  But I can not found more documents about it.

```
@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    super.computeScroll();
    if (sc.computeScrollOffset()) {
        int stx = sc.getStartX(), sty = sc.getStartY();
        int cx = sc.getCurrX(), cy = sc.getCurrY();
        int edx = sc.getFinalX(), edy = sc.getFinalY();
        if (cx <= edx && cy <= edy) {
            this.center = new Point(this.center.x+cx-stx,this.center.y+cy-sty);
        }
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }

}
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.i("event", "fling:" + e1.getX() + "," + e2.getX());
    sc.forceFinished(true);
    sc.fling(0, 0, velocityX, velocityY, -30, 30, -30, 30);
    return true;
}
```

When I ran the application, I can not get the expected fling effect.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: If your problem is that animation sometimes doesn't run, sometimes runs perfect and sometimes just jumps to the end coordinates. It can be because you probably need some sort of invalidate() after sc.fling(); sc.fling just starts internal calculations in OverScroller and computeScroll() will be called only on next invalidate. Had this issue.